# Unable to search for parent and child documents using Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed a child document in Elasticsearch as follows:

```
{
 _parent: chow-demo
 _index: prototype_2013.01.02
 _type: chow-clfg
 _id: l7jvEgD-SrG-Ws_9ab52IA
 _score: 11.600378
 _source: {
  chow-clfg: {
  @type: chow-clfg
  clfg: Cg5iUlAvU9IIAAAA8Rg
  @timestamp: 2013-01-02T10:15:00.000Z
  count: 1
  }
 }
}
```

The parent has at least 2 records that has **clfg** as a common identifier as follows:

```
{
 _index: "prototype_2013.01.02",
 _type: chow-demo, 
 clfg: Cg5iUlAvU9IIAAAA8Rg,
 obid: 97066795
}
```

However when I query using the "has_child" query, I get no results:

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200:/prototype_2013.01.02/chow-demo/_search"
{
 "query": {
  "has_child": {
   "type": "chow-clfg",
   "query": {
    "term": {
      "clfg": "Cg5iUlAvU9IIAAAA8Rg"
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

However when I query individually for the documents, there were correct results returned. Why is that so? Isn't the parent routing supposed to be able to identify results using the child using the parent field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When child is indexed, its "_parent" field should contain the parent's id (not parent's type as it seems to be in you case).

Comment: So you mean that the _parent only routes to unique documents? Because I have unique ids that run across different documents and I want to be able to query them using parent and child filter, so am I getting it wrong about parent/child mapping?

Comment: Each document has one id that it's indexed with. This id is unique among all documents with the same type. If you will try to create another document with the same id, the previous version of the document will be overwritten. You should be able to get document using something `curl localhost:9200/index_name/type/id`. So, this `id` of the parent document has to be specified in the `parent` parameter on URI. One child document can have only one parent. But different child documents can point to the same parent.

Comment: I see, I mistook the _parent mapping field to map types, but there is no mapping to parent document's IDs, hence there will never be a result. Thanks for clarifying!